# Does the CONCURRENCY=shell tweak work in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, boot, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do newer Ubuntu releases benefit from multicore processors at boot time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61957/do-newer-ubuntu-releases-benefit-from-multicore-processors-at-boot-time)

I have a multi-core processor, so I just thought I'd make use of this tweak. But before I do tweak it, I would like to know whether this tweak still works in 11.10?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/61957/do-newer-ubuntu-releases-benefit-from-multicore-processors-at-boot-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu has had a concurrent (specifically, an event based) init daemon in `upstart` for a number of releases - since Ubuntu 8.04 at least.  Most of the boot up process is handled by upstart scripts, and has been since Ubuntu 10.04.

In short, no.  `CONCURRENCY=shell` doesn't do anything useful anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You will save a few nanoseconds, because the remaining `rc.d` style scripts will run simultaneously.

For example when booting, the system has to run the scripts in `/etc/rc2.d` directory

```
S20kerneloops
S20speech-dispatcher
S20unattended-upgrades
S25bluetooth
S50pulseaudio
S50rsync
S50saned
S70dns-clean
S70pppd-dns
S75sudo
S99acpi-support
S99grub-common
S99ondemand
S99rc.local
```

The scripts with the same number in its name will run *concurrently*, saving a tiny little time.