# What are the differences between concurrency=shell and concurrency=makefile?

Tags: command-line, makefile

I feel that 11.10 boots very slow on my netbook. Many people said that changing concurrency method to shell in `/etc/init.d/rc` will speed up boot process, but the comment in the file said that the valid options of concurrency are 'none' and 'makefile', and the concurrency method since 2010-05-14 was makefile.

What are the differences between both? Is shell concurrency method still used until now?

Comment: i guess `none` will run all services sequentially, while `makefile` will run at the same time services with the same "precedence"

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/83569/does-the-concurrency-shell-tweak-work-in-11-10